# I need help [ with / to / verb+ing ]

Tags: grammar

Can someone explain to me if those sentences are corrects and what is the difference between them:

- I need help with moving these books.
- I need help moving these books.
- I need help for moving these books.
- I need help to move these books.

Answer (score 2):

**These are all understandable and correct**

---

> I need help with moving these books.

This is a very complete, fully comprehensible sentence - that is not ambiguous.

> I need help [with] moving these books.

Effectively, this is the same as the first sentence using an implied *with*.

> I need help for moving these books.

This sentence is correct, and understandable. However it can sound a little jarred compared to the others - and is perhaps less common.

The main difference with this phrase, is it makes the request a little less personal. In the other sentences, you are making it clear that you will be moving books - and need help to do it. Here, it is more ambiguous about whether you are going to be included in moving the books or not.

Potentially, this kind of phrase could be used for hiring. It is states you have work needing completed, and need help/workers to facilitate that.

That said, you wouldn't get any funny looks by using this phrase - it would be understood.

> I need help [in order] to move these books.

This is again a complete sentence, with an optionally implied *in order*. It makes it clear that you need help so that you can move the books.

Comment: I agree, `help with` is the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think these bellow are correct (http://pt.bab.la/verbo/ingles/move).

- I need help moving these books.
- I need help to move these books.
- I need help with moving these books.

Incorrect
 - I need help for moving these books.

Comment: Hi, Danilo - actually, the third one is completely correct too.  It's not just a matter of verb conjugation, but what prepositions you can use with the verb.

Answer (score 0):

In your examples, "help" is a noun, not a verb. The actual verb is "need", so next verb would be a gerund (ing form).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. Your answer could be improved by providing references. One line answers are discouraged on this site. See [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score -1):

The verb *help* can be followed by Full infinitive and Bare infinitive:

- > I need help move these books.
- > I need help to move these books.

To use the ing form you can use *help with* or *help in*:

- > I need help with moving these books.
- > I need help in moving these books.

"I need help for moving these books" is incorrect sentence I think.